# Multi-dimensional interpolation routine that preserves shape AND differentiability

Tags: computation

I am looking at two-dimensional gridded data from a kinked function, but need to make it smooth. Is there a two-dimensional version of the Schumaker-routine? I would also greatly appreciate pointers to MatLab code!

Comment: What do you mean by **preserves shape**? What do you mean by **preserves  differentiability** if kinked functions are not differentiable at the kink points? Perhaps you could post a one dimensional image of a kinked function, a sample of points at which values are taken, and an interpolation line that has the properties you desire.